# SharePoint 2010 without using User Profile Synchronization Service

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We are going to implement a SharePoint 2010 farm, but due to some issues, we will not be able to create an account with the necessary privileges to use "User Profile Synchronization Service".

My question is, can we run SharePoint 2010 Standard edition without using the User Profile Synchronization Service?  If so, how do we import user profile information?

Thanks in advanced,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

i think you can but I believe that you would then need even more privileges than to use the service in order to export the profiles manually.  It would be far easier and more secure to resolve your issues first.  The only privs you need are replicate directory changes and create child objects and write